# What are at(1) compatible time formats?

Tags: datetime, time, standards, datetime-format, graphite

I found the quote below in [Graphite docs](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#from-until):

> ABSOLUTE_TIME is in the format HH:MM_YYMMDD, YYYYMMDD, MM/DD/YY, or any other `at(1)`-compatible time format.

What does mean `at(1)` and how can I get the list of `at(1)`-compatible time formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`at(1)` refers to a *nix command named `at` found in the section `1` of man pages. In a command line/shell, type `man 1 at` to read the documentation,
or see e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html